# Fails to run a Jar file on macOS using Zulu JRE (8.271)

Tags: java, macos, class, jar, program-entry-point

`java -jar jarfile` works perfectly on Windows/Ubuntu, yet on macOS, I keep getting "Could not find or load main class."
Not only that, when I run the jar using Oracle's JRE - it works (the oracle's JRE isn't part of the path, so I write the absolute path in order to verify the right version I'm running).
So using absolute paths to the `jre\bin\java` files, once to the Oracle's JRE (works), once to the Zulu's Mac version JRE and I get "Could not find or load main class."

Any idea?
I used a simple `java -jar jarfile` command.
The Manifest file in the Jar does include a Main file reference (an obfuscated Main file) yet has no reference to a classpath (we wrap everything inside one JAR so we don't have any external jar dependency).